# Displaying select element as menu on screen html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'd like to create a something similar to a select element with different values and display it visually on the screen. Something like the image below.

[image]

What I intend to do with this is change the contents of the website below based on what option is selected. Each box would act as a toggle button when selected and then change the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So this is basically only a different visual design for a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with JavaScript and HTML. Create a select option with HTML and write code in JavaScript to control what to show.